# Compiler optimizations not compiling constant?

Tags: c, gcc, arm, ld

I have the following string declared as a constant in my code. The purpose is to provide a crude and simple way of storing simple metadata in the compiled output.

```
const char myString1[] ="abc123\0";
const char myString2[] = {'a','b','c','1','2','3','\0'};
```

When I inspect the output with a hex editor, I see other string constants but "abc123" does not appear.  This leads me to believe that the optimizations that are enabled are causing the lines not to be compiled, as they are never referenced in the program.

Is there a way in code to force this to compile, or another way (in code) of getting this metadata into the binary?  I don't want to do any manipulation of the binary post-compile, the goal is to keep it as simple as possible.

**compiler flags**

`-O2 -g -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -fno-builtin -ffunction-sections -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb`

Comment: I think it would help to post the compiler flags being used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come up with a solution that uses attributes and involves modifying the link script.

First I define a custom section called ".metadata".

```
__attribute__ ((section(".metadata")))
```

Then, in the `SECTIONS` block of the .ld script I added a `KEEP(*(.metadata))` which will force the linker to include `.metadata` even if it's not used

```
.text :
{
    KEEP(*(.isr_vector))
    KEEP(*(.metadata))
    *(.text*)
    *(.rodata*)

} > MFlash32
```

**NOTE**

I found that the `__attribute__` keyword had to be on the same line as the variable or else it didn't actually show up in the binary, though the .metadata section did show up in the memory map.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for the `used` attribute:

> `used'
>
> > This attribute, attached to a variable, means that the variable
> >     must be emitted even if it appears that the variable is not
> >     referenced.
> >
> > When applied to a static data member of a C++ class template, the
> >     attribute also means that the member will be instantiated if the
> >     class itself is instantiated.

Apply it like

```
__attribute__((used))
const char myString1[] ="abc123\0";
__attribute__((used))
const char myString2[] = {'a','b','c','1','2','3','\0'};
```

Given the compiler flags you posted, it is almost certainly the linker. The `-ffunction-sections` flag puts each definition into its own section in the object files. This allows the linker to easily determine that a data item or function is not referenced and omit it from the final binary.

Comment: +1, IAR compiler has `__root` and I was looking for something similar with `gcc`.

Comment: I've tried both the 'used' and 'unused' attributes with no luck.  I'll do some more poking around in the GCC docs for attributes and see what I can come up with.

Comment: @BrianV I'm not that familiar with compiling for arm, but it sounds like the linker is the one dropping the data. That is, unless you're actually looking at the object file and not finding the data.

Comment: @GeoffReedy Your reply has sent me down the right path.  It looks like the ARM toolchain has some specific attributes to do facilitate exactly the sort of thing I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Use the binutils `strings` command to see if these strings are present in your binary.

If they have been optimized out, you can try to use the `volatile` qualifier when you declare them. Note that if they are not used even with the `volatile` qualifier some compilers can still optimized them out.

Answer (score 0):

If you have these variables in file scope, the compiler *must* provide the strings, since he can't know if they will be used from a different compilation unit. So any of your ".o" files where you place these variables, must contain the string.

Now a clever linker could decide for the final binary that these constants are not needed. (I have never observed that, though.) If this is the case for your platform, you should use the variable on a "hypothetical" path, that in reality will never be taken by the program. Something like

```
int main(int argc, char*argv[]){
  switch (argv[0][0]) {
    case 1: return myString1[argv[0][1]];
    case 2: return myString2[argv[0][1]];
  }
  ...
}
```